# Ask for a delete

Tags: discussion, contests

I answered this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549841/a-game-of-probability

And was ask for a delete, because the question is a part of some current challenge on a site. I was down voted by the guy who seems to be in charge of the challenge. What should I do ?

Comment: Then just do it.

Comment: Downvoting you was perhaps a bit harsh, but as an ex-participant (and current part time organizer) of math-contests I second the request. Your answer will get the rep it deserves later. I hope Calvin will remind us all to check it out after the deadline. The asker is the cheater, you had no way of knowing. For now delete it.

Comment: @Jyrki: While you can't know in the sense of having `P(it's not a duck)=0`, the OP does both look like a duck and quack like a duck.

Comment: Well, you're right, Hurkyl, in the sense that the question smells of OP trying to cheat somehow. In my book an attempt to cheat in a contest is a more severe offense than just attempting to get somebody to do one's homework. "Xoff had no way of knowing that it was from an ongoing contest" would be a more accurate way of phrasing what I meant.

Comment: Ok, I deleted my answer.